# How to lcfirst each group of words?

Tags: perl

Why this is not working as I expected?

```sh
$ echo 'JOHN, BO PEEP, BoPeep' | perl -0777ne 'map { print ($_) if $_ ne uc($_) } split /,/'
 BoPeep

$ echo 'JOHN, BO PEEP, BoPeep' | perl -0777ne 'map { print lcfirst($_) if $_ ne uc($_) } split /,/'
 BoPeep
```

The only difference between the two commands is `print ($_)` vs `print lcfirst($_)`, while I was expecting that `print lcfirst($_)` would output `boPeep` instead.

What am I missing?

Sample input:

`JOHN, BO PEEP, BoPeep, AVG, Hex_String_Literal, Time_String, MODULE`

Comment: Because the first character in `" BoPeep"` is a space. Maybe you want `split /, */`?

Comment: I voted to close as a typo but you can delete it.

Comment: No, it is not a typo @ggorlen, it's my blind spot actually, as I would unable to tell the problem and come up with `split /, */` myself. Besides, with zdim's answer, I think I'll just leave it here.

Comment: Yes, but the "typo" reason is a shorthand for a few other things. The broad category includes "unhelpful to future visitors" -- basically forgetting/not realizing that there's an invisible space at the beginning of your string is a "brain fart" and not a common problem category that needs to exist as a curated resource on the site. Hence the "typo" reason. The full text is "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

Comment: How's this. I am going to post this as an answer, if you don't want to delete the question (I think it's a fair contribution since this is a common mistake, and it contains other possibly useful tidbits).  @ggorlen -- if you wish to post an answer, being first to the reason, let me know

Comment: Ok with me @zdim, but pls keep in mind of the _"separated by space, with lcfirst"_ part of the requirement. I.e., with the updated sample data in OP, the correct output should be `boPeep hex_String_Literal time_String`. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that splitting on a comma alone leaves the leading spaces in each term.

One way to take care of that is to split on all that can come between tokens of interest, here `/\s*,\s*/` (recall that [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) takes a full legit regex there).  With other simplifications

```
echo "JOHN, BO PEEP, BoPeep, AVG, Hex_String_Literal, Time_String, MODULE"
    | perl -nlE'$_ ne uc($_) and say lcfirst($_) for split /\s*,\s*/'
```

This prints words `boPeep`, `hex_String_Literal`, `time_String` each on a separate line.  To print them as clarified, on one line separated by spaces, we need a little more. For example

```
perl -nE'say join " ", map { $_ ne uc($_) ? lcfirst($_) : () } split /\s*,\s*/'
```

This uses a trick to filter by `map`: return an empty list `()` for what we want to filter out (all-caps words), which gets flattened into nothing in the overall output list.  Or, filter then process further

```
perl -nE'say join " ", map { lcfirst($_) } grep { $_ ne uc($_) } split /\s*,\s*/'
```

This processes the list from `split` first, to `grep` through it, and then goes over its output list of remaining items with `map`. This is likely a bit less efficient than having a ternary in one pass over the whole list, but that's surely not going to show in any reasonable work loads.

Some comments

- I've dropped `-0777` as I am not sure of its utility -- if this runs on a file and a multiline chunks in text need be processed then we need some other provisions for that anyway. If it goes line-by-line then there's no need for it. Put it back if needed :)
- That convenient [`-E` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-E-commandline), which provides `say` (and *all* other features!) isn't good in the eyes of future compatibility. If that is or can become an issue then use `CORE::say`, or of course `print "...", "\n"`, and keep `-e` instead of `-E`